# return the first index with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of monsters. monster is an object for example

```
{
type: "FIRE",
name: "Sosa",
original: true,
food: ["meet","egg"] // cannot contains 2 identical food
}
```

what I want is to return the index of the first monster having an X food I have tried this function:

```
let x = "meet";
let index = -1;
let i = -1;
animals.forEach((animal) => {
  i++;
  animal.food.forEach((food) => {
    if (food === "x") index = i;
  });
});
return index;
```

this is not working for all cases. I am new to programming please some explications and help I will be thankfull

Comment: If you want to _find_ something in the array you should use the `find` method, not `forEach`.

Comment: I am a bigginer and I am learning forEach this is why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is returning the `index` of the last found item not the first. so it works only when the last found item is at the same time the first found ie only one item is found.

if you really want to use `forEach` an alternative is to store all found indexes :

```
var foundIndexes = [];

// your code 
if(food === x) foundIndexes.push(i);
//your code

const myIndex = foundIndexes.length == 0 ?  -1 : foundIndexes[0] // that means if the array is still empty myIndex = -1 else myIndex = the first element of foundIndexes ie the first found index
return myIndex;
```

you can also use [array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) it does exactly what you are looking for or even [array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to stop the loop once you find the first item

Comment: I don't understand the last line before return

Comment: [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:~:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) go ahead and learn more. I described it briefly in //

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#findIndex` in conjunction with `Array#includes`.

```js
let idx = animals.findIndex(a => a.food.includes('x'));
```